# SHV ID : 79856 Can not create validator

Tags: c, com, network-programming, registration, dcom

I have implemented SdkSha and  SdkSHV  from windows netds samples.
The NPS is configured on 64 bit Windows 2008 Server R2 operating system.
When I added  SHV.dll by regsvr32 command , the SHV was added to system health validators list on nps console and The SHV UI is displayed correctly
but  this

> Error :
>   SHV ID : 79856 Can not create validator

was showed in NAP Server Events and my SHV and SHA couldn't communicate with each other.
Does anyone know what to do? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the same. Basically, your 'system health validator' dll requires access permissions for read and execute. If your dll is not having these rights it will give this error.